# Add button like "New Mail" button of Gmail app

Tags: android, button, material-design

I want to add a button like the "New Mail" button in the Gmail app (The circle button bottom of right with pen icon), which is floating on the screen.
Can someone show me how to do this? is it possible to do this without the Material Design guidelines?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This library: https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button
seems to do a decent job of replicating the Floating Action Button, as well as some of the menu interactions if you're interested in those.

Answer (score 3):

Or just import the official Google FAB sample in Android Studio:

File > Import Sample > search for FloatingActionButtonBasic.

The FloatingActionButton library is part of The Android Open Source Project

Comment: NOTE: This project is only for API level 21. Won't work on anything prior.